# Incorrect path to addons running odoo.py in Bitnami Odoo Stack that is correct in openerp-server.conf

Tags: odoo-8, bitnami

I'm trying to run `~/ERP/bitnami-odoo/python/bin/python ~/ERP/bitnami-odoo/apps/odoo/bin/odoo.py help` and now I am getting this error:

```
~/ERP/bitnami-odoo/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.9.0-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:1268: UserWarning: ~/ERP/bitnami-odoo/.tmp is writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a more secure location (set with .set_extraction_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/ERP/bitnami-odoo/apps/odoo/bin/odoo.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('odoo==8.0.post20151126', 'odoo.py')
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 719, in run_script

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1504, in run_script

  File "~/ERP/bitnami-odoo/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/odoo.py", line 160, in <module>
    main()
  File "~/ERP/bitnami-odoo/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/odoo.py", line 157, in main
    openerp.cli.main()
  File "~/ERP/bitnami-odoo/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/cli/__init__.py", line 58, in main
    for m in module.get_modules():
  File "~/ERP/bitnami-odoo/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/module.py", line 351, in get_modules
    plist.extend(listdir(ad))
  File "~/ERP/bitnami-odoo/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/module.py", line 346, in listdir
    return map(clean, filter(is_really_module, os.listdir(dir)))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/ERP/odoo/openerp/addons'
```

This directory is not correct (obviously), but I can't find where it is defined. The full path should be `~/ERP/bitnami-odoo/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons` and this error shows a wrong path without `/bitnami-odoo/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/`

I've tried passing the path to openerp-server.conf `~/ERP/bitnami-odoo/python/bin/python ~/ERP/bitnami-odoo/apps/odoo/bin/odoo.py help -c ~/ERP/bitnami-odoo/apps/odoo/conf/openerp-server.conf`, where the addons path is the correct, but the error continues. Is it a bitnami error? If it is not, Where do I can solve that.

Note: I use ~/ to not expose the whole path. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a default config file in `~/.openerp_server.rc`.
you can use  `addons_path =` to set addons file.

Comment: It doesn't have a .openerp_server.rc, only the opnererp-server.conf and I'am using it.

Comment: run `odoo.py --save`. this will create the file.

Comment: The correct filename was .openerp_serverrc (without the second dot). Thanks